# braces on virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard, lubuntu

I currently have a Lubuntu 17.10 virtual machine running on my QNAP NAS through the "Virtualization station". I use this virtual machine mainly to learn a bit of javascript, but something strange keeps happening to me...

When I'm at home with the keyboard of my MacBook and I connect to the site where the virtual machine runs, I can make braces through the combination <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>è</kbd>. Instead, when I'm in the office and I connect with the office PC at the same site but with another keyboard (Italian extended) I can not make the brace. Can someone help me?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the web interface?

Comment: may be an issue with the keyboard configuration (the two keyboards are different...)?

Comment: Good call, if possible I would set the keyboards to the same layout just to see if that is the problem... If not, I would go back to an issue with the web interface.

Comment: Are you logging into the GUI of lubuntu through the web interface of the vm. If so I would install onboard an onscreen keyboard to help with debugging if you can't get braces and see if the brace works that way on the broken keyobard layout. If that is true it is a web interface problem most likely.

Comment: I installed the onscreen keyboard and the problem seems to be that when I press the altgr key, the key remains pressed, confusing the rest. May be a problem with the web interface like you say